# Plaid MFA response is incorrect

Tags: webhooks, plaid

I am testing the user flow in answering the three questions for "bofa". I am trying to simulate a user who puts an incorrect answer into the question passed to them via Plaid.

My raw POST is like

```
 "POST /connect/step?client_id=blah&secret=blah&mfa=1again&access_token=XYZ&type=bofa&options[webhook]=http%3A%2F%2Fx.y.zom%2Fplaid_webhook%2Fantennas HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: tartan.plaid.com\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n"
```

Notice my incorrect answer ("1again" instead of "again"), but also notice the presence of the access token ("XYZ"), which is correct.

This is the response

```
-> "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
 -> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n"
 -> "Date: Wed, 19 Mar 2014 20:20:20 GMT\r\n"
 -> "X-Powered-By: Express\r\n"
 -> "Content-Length: 144\r\n"
 -> "Connection: Close\r\n"
 -> "\r\n"
 reading 144 bytes...
 -> "{\"code\":1000,\"message\":\"access_token missing\",\"resolve\":\"You need to include the access_token that you received from the original submit call.\"}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything should be running smoothly with the mfa user flow in the sandbox now! If you use "1again" (for example) instead of the correct response "again", you will receive an appropriate error code response:

```
{"code":1203,"message":"invalid mfa","resolve":"The MFA response provided was not correct."}
```